# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) while decoding HTTPResponse

Tags: python, httpclient, urllib, httpresponse

I try to send a POST request that surely works well.

```
import json
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': {}
}

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection({host})
    conn.request("POST", {endpoint}, body_json, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()  # response is HTTPResponse
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

The `data` is equal to `b''`, which means bytes.

I tried to convert bytes to string:

```
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-0ec4b22ab6c2> in <module>
      1 string = data.decode('utf-8').strip("'<>() ").replace('\'', '\"')
----> 2 json_obj = json.loads(string)

    /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
        352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
        353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
        355     if cls is None:
        356         cls = JSONDecoder
    
    /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
        337 
        338         """
    --> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        340         end = _w(s, end).end()
        341         if end != len(s):
    
    /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
        355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        356         except StopIteration as err:
    --> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        358         return obj, end
    
    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I solve this error, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The key is here:

> The data is equal to b'', which means bytes.

Not exactly. `b''` means **empty** bytes.

Because `json.loads` could easily read bytes, but an empty document, be it bytes or unicode string causes the `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

TL/DR: the error is there before you try to load an empty JSON document.

Comment: Does it mean that the endpoint returns an empty response `response = conn.getresponse()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly; the response from the server is an empty buffer, which isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Hmm, so weird. Do you know why the responses might be empty? Wrong Body?

Comment: I tried to pass `body` as dictionary: `body={'param1': 'val1'}` as follows `urlencode(body)`, but got `b'{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid Request.","innererror":{"code":"EmptyRequest","message":"Request body must be present."}}}'`